# Disabling IP Routing Mode on Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, routing, ip-routing

Is there a way to disable the windows 2008's routing mode from the command line (or GUI)?
That is, I want the following result when running "ipconfig /all"

> IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this in the registry.

Run regedit

navigate to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
```

change the value of `IPEnableRouter` from 1 to 0

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I'm truly looking for a command line (or GUI) way to do that. I already knew about the registry key.